Обособление причастного оборота решительно необходимо?
«Этим, равно как и материалом (стекло), обозначена чистота инициатив, их, освобожденная от материальной тяги, идеальность». Н. Пунин, Памятник III Интернационала 1920.
Вопрос об обособлении: так ли оно здесь необходимо?


Я бы оформила так: Этим, равно как и материалом (стекло), обозначена чистота инициатив, их, освобожденная от материальной тяги, идеальность (Н. Пунин. Памятник III Интернационала. Июль 1920 г.). (https://ussr.totalarch.com/monument-to-the-3-international-tatlin-project) Интересный вопрос.

Спасибо! Не стал «марать» оригинал.


Обособить оборот  равно как и  нужно по аналогии с оборотом также как и, который обособляется по правилам Розенталя, п.3(2).

Этим, равно как и материалом (стекло), обозначена чистота инициатив, их, освобожденная от материальной тяги, идеальность.

Причастный оборот можно не обособлять:

Этим, равно как и материалом (стекло), обозначена чистота инициатив, их освобожденная от материальной тяги идеальность.
Розенталь, пункт 4: Ваш проверенный на практике метод заслуживает внимания.
Здесь актуализация оборота, но при обособлении много запятых, поэтому текст сложно понимается.
Из Нацкорпуса:
Александр Кацва. Россия 1990-х // «Отечественные записки», 2003
Однако между этими этапами, равно как и внутри них, движение развивалось крайне неравномерно.

Вопрос же о причастном... В метках обозначил, а в тексте поленился.

Поскольку (при множестве запятых) можно и то и это, не подошёл бы такой вариант, как обособление парой тире: «...чистота инициатив, их — освобожденная от материальной тяги — идеальность»?
